# 500 Internal Server Error after renaming htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, error-handling

I'm getting 500 errors showing on my site after renaming htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Comment: This is generally expected, you need the .htaccess file enabled for most features of Joomla

Comment: How can 500 errors be *expected*?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is generally expected and Joomla can function perfectly without .htaccess being enabled (or at least mod_rewrite enabled)

Comment: Just enable "Use URL Rewriting" in Global Configuration from the Admin panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just some additional information on this error, copied right out of the default `htaccess.txt` file that comes with Joomla:

```
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Another line that might cause errors is the `RewriteBase` (home page will work, all links will give a `404 Not found` error):

```
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /
```

This line is needed if your Joomla installation is located in a subfolder of your domain. Add the name of the subfolder after the `/` (e.g. `RewriteBase /joomla`). Note that this is *not* needed when Joomla inside a subfolder used as addon domain in cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue, on line 19 of the file, I replaced

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

with

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Not sure if this is further information, or the answer :)  Can you accept the answer if it is, or move the changes you made to the question as further detail. :)

Comment: This has solved it, I've put it as an answer for anyone else. I can't accept the answer until 2 days time

Comment: Cool...it was asked and answered so quickly, I wasn't sure :)

Answer (score 0):

In my setup, a `wamp` update had reset my `Apache` `.conf` file, and I found out that the module `mod_rewrite` was disabled!

So I just enabled it by un-commenting that specific line and It was working fine, after **restarting the server**, also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30709854/807104).

Answer (score -1):

My website's problem is solved by changing 2 lines of `.htaccess` file:

- Comment `Options +FollowSymLinks` as below:

  ```
  #Options +FollowSymLinks
  ```
- Uncomment `#RewriteEngine On` as below:

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  ```