# Internal Server Error on Godaddy Shared Host

Tags: installation, upgrade

After uploading my Joomla! 3.3.6 installation (that I had upgraded from 2.5 on localhost) on my Godaddy shared host, I cannot access the site: I got 500 Internal Server Error (after waiting for ~30 seconds).

When trying going to ACP, I could access the login page, however after entering the username/password, I got the same error.

I could not find any solutions that work, including [this one](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=520799).

The .htaccess file (located in Joomla! root) can be downloaded from here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/r63jowwxtb6skp5/htaccess

Hope somebody can help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Works ok on localhost?

Comment: Is your Joomla installation located in the `/home` directory, accessed by `http://yourdomain.com/home/index.php`? If not, you should change the line `RewriteBase /home` in your .htaccess file.

Comment: @johnny_s: yes, works fine on localhost. I have an IPB forum hosted on the same server and it works just fine, so I think there's something wrong on the Joomla!'s side rather than the server's.

Comment: @johanpw: yes Joomla! installation is located in the /home directory. To be more specific, it is located in html_public/mydomain.com/home, where html_public/mydomain.com/ is the directory to which I point the domain, which is from another provider.

Comment: OK, but how do you access your website? If you use `http://example.com/` then you should change that line to `RewriteBase /` in your htaccess file. [This answer](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/500-internal-server-error-after-renaming-htaccess-txt-to-htaccess/5595#5595) explains more about this. Try making the change and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @johanpw: The website's address is: http://example.com/home. Changing to RewriteBase / does not help :(

Comment: it was worth a try... can you also try changing `#Options +FollowSymLinks` to `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: check the $live_site variable as @johanpw has suggested. This caught me out a few times.

Comment: @johnny_s: I tried uploading and restoring again the database and it seems to be working (my bad, sorry!). However, it remains a very serious problem, to which I haven't found a solution yet: the images on the website are not displayed! Please see here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/images-not-displayed-after-migrating-from-localhost-internal-server-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often hard to find the reason for 500 Internal Server errors, but here's a couple of things you can check and/or test.

(Note: it has been reported that on GoDaddy, changes to `.htaccess` files need 10-30 minutes to take effect. Personally I've never had that problem, but it might be worth trying to wait)

### Re-upload your site

It might not make any difference, but if possible, remove your site from the server and re-upload it. I recommend using [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) for this.

### Disable .htaccess

Try to temporary remove or rename your `.htaccess` file.

### Cookie Domain

In your `configuration.php` file, check if the following variables has any values. If they do, change them to this:

```
public $cookie_domain = '';
public $cookie_path = '';
```

### Cache problem

It's possible that it has to do with a cache problem, or a caching system not supported by GoDaddy. Check the following lines in your `configuration.php` file, and change them to the following:

```
public $cache_handler = 'file';
public $caching = '0';
public $session_handler = 'database';
```

### $live_site variable

Verify your `$live_site` variable in `configuration.php`. It should be empty, or read

```
public $live_site = "http://www.example.com/home";
```

Comment: Thanks, johanpw. I tried uploading and restoring again the database and it seems to be working (my bad, sorry!). However, it remains a very serious problem, to which I haven't found a solution yet: the images on the website are not displayed! Please see here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/images-not-displayed-after-migrating-from-localhost-internal-server-error