# Images not displayed after migrating from localhost (Internal Server Error)

Tags: installation, migration, images

After uploading my Joomla! 3.3 from localhost, I got a very serious problem: **the images on the website are not displayed!**

When I tried accessing the URL of an image, I got an **Internal Server Error**. The images are well on the server, with chmod 644 (and 755 for the image folders).

Hope somebody can help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because your website is located inside a subdirectory on your domain (example.com/home), it is possible that the **parent** directory contains a `.htaccess`-file. Rules in this file would also affect your Joomla site. Are you able to provide a link to your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with your `images` folder. If I visit http://example.com/media, I get the expected blank page (the empty `index.html` that is located inside each folder to avoid directory listing).

However, http://example.com/images gives a 500 error, so none of your images in that folder are available. The thumbnails show up because a plugin (plg_readlesstext) caches your images and creates a thumbnail in the `cache` folder, outside the `images` folder.

Check if you have a `.htaccess` file inside your `images` folder. If not, try disabling the Readless plugin and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!! I created an .htaccess file in that folder yesterday, based on a suggestion of a person on Joomla!'s forum. (The content of the file is "php_flag engine off". That person said that this is more secure). I don't know if he's right but I have to remove it :P
Thank you so much!!!